# Trying to install laravel 6, but command return 5.8.*

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, laravel-6

I'm trying to install laravel 6 running the command:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel {appName}`

But this command returns to me 5.8.* version:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.8.35)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v5.8.35): Loading from cache ...
```

I'm using Wampserver 3.2. I've selected the 7.4.0 version, and I've tried to change CLI also (right click on tray icon > tools > php CLI version).

When I access the `phpinfo.php` on localhost, gives me the right version (7.4.0), but typing the command `php -v`, returns to me:

```
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

I'm posting this information, but I don't know if it really has anything to do with downloading version 5.8. *. Any sugestion?

Comment: PHP requirements for Laravel 6 is PHP 7.2. If your CLI is putting out 7.1, then that won't work so it grabs the older version. Update the php.ini for your CLI to use the latest PHP.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, this is what I thought. Where do I find this within php.ini?
I am trying to modify the CLI version through the Wamp tray icon, but without positive results.

Comment: You usually will have two versions of your php.ini -- web and cli. If you want to see the location of your cli version, you can run `php -v | grep php.ini` in your console.

Comment: I've identified the problem with your advice Jeremy. I had uninstalled an old version of the wampserver and the new installation did not take the new path to the php.ini CLI of the new version of the wamp. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure no problem. It's a pretty common issue.

Comment: Kindly remove other Php  versions you don’t use, restart your Apache, system if possible. Than use this command with blog behind or without blog. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.0.*"

Answer (score -1):

Please update with command

```
composer update
compose upgrade
```